# работа с массивами и json в javascript

Tags: javascript, json, рекурсия

есть json

```
{"Data": [{"Uzel": "asd","Number": "1","Parent": "0","Update": "3"},{"Uzel": "asd","Number": "1.1","Parent": "1","Update": "2"},{"Uzel": "asd","Number": "2.2.1.2.1.2","Parent": "2.2.1.2.1","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "asd","Number": "1.1.1","Parent": "1.1","Update": "2"},{"Uzel": "asd","Number": "1.1.2","Parent": "1.1","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "zxc","Number": "1.1.3","Parent": "1.1","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "ert","Number": "1.1.4","Parent": "1.1","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "fgh","Number": "1.2","Parent": "1","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "cvb","Number": "1.2.1","Parent": "1.2","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "2012 год ","Number": "1.2.2","Parent": "1.2","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "uio","Number": "1.2.3","Parent": "1.2","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "2014 год ","Number": "1.2.4","Parent": "1.2","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "xxx","Number": "1.2.5","Parent": "1.2","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "xxx","Number": "1.3","Parent": "1","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "zzz","Number": "1.3.1","Parent": "1.3","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "aaa","Number": "1.3.2","Parent": "1.3","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "qqq","Number": "1.3.3","Parent": "1.3","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "vvv","Number": "1.3.4","Parent": "1.3","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "vvv","Number": "1.4","Parent": "1","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "www","Number": "1.4.1","Parent": "1.4","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "eee","Number": "1.4.2","Parent": "1.4","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "uuu","Number": "1.4.3","Parent": "1.4","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "iii","Number": "1.4.4","Parent": "1.4","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "ttt","Number": "1.4.5","Parent": "1.4","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "uuu","Number": "1.4.6","Parent": "1.4","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "nnn","Number": "1.5","Parent": "1","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "ooo","Number": "1.5.1","Parent": "1.5","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "nnn","Number": "1.5.2","Parent": "1.5","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "ppp","Number": "1.5.3","Parent": "1.5","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "bbb","Number": "1.5.4","Parent": "1.5","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "fff","Number": "1.5.5","Parent": "1.5","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "jjj","Number": "1.5.6","Parent": "1.5","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "lll","Number": "2","Parent": "0","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "mmm","Number": "2.1","Parent": "2","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "eee","Number": "2.1.1","Parent": "2.1","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "rrr","Number": "2.1.1.1","Parent": "2.1.1","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "opop","Number": "2.1.1.1.1","Parent": "2.1.1.1","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "asd","Number": "2.1.1.1.2","Parent": "2.1.1.1","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "asd","Number": "2.1.1.1.3","Parent": "2.1.1.1","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "asd","Number": "2.1.1.2","Parent": "2.1.1","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "asd","Number": "2.1.1.2.1","Parent": "2.1.1.2","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "fgh","Number": "2.1.1.2.2","Parent": "2.1.1.2","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "tyu","Number": "2.1.1.3","Parent": "2.1.1","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "uio","Number": "2.1.1.4","Parent": "2.1.1","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "zxc","Number": "2.1.1.5","Parent": "2.1.1","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "dsa","Number": "2.1.1.5.1","Parent": "2.1.1.5","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "poi","Number": "2.1.2","Parent": "2.1","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "qaxz","Number": "2.1.2.1","Parent": "2.1.2","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "ert","Number": "2.1.2.1.1","Parent": "2.1.2.1","Update": "0"}]}
```

ее надо перевести в такой вид

```
 {"Data": [{"Uzel": "asd","Number": "1","Parent": "0","Update": "3", children:[{"Uzel": "asd","Number": "1.1","Parent": "1","Update": "2","children":[{"Uzel": "asd","Number": "1.1.1","Parent": "1.1","Update": "2"},{"Uzel": "asd","Number": "1.1.2","Parent": "1.1","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "zxc","Number": "1.1.3","Parent": "1.1","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "ert","Number": "1.1.4","Parent": "1.1","Update": "0"}],{"Uzel": "fgh","Number": "1.2","Parent": "1","Update": "0"}}]}]}
```

то есть добавить еще один параметр children и все элементы массива у который parent связан с number другого элемента положить внутр этого элемента.

вложенность многоуровневый - у children может быть свои children а у него свои соответственно и так далее.

понимаю что рекурсия но никак не могу сделать помогите пожалуйста.  Не высылаю код потому что в корни не правильный. JAVASCRIPT

Comment: код нужен как раз для того, чтобы можно было сказать: что именно в нем неправильно

Comment: Я копирую массив и в новом пишу сначала родителей(тех у кого парент=0) а потом по второму перебираю детей. но не могу сообразить как внутрь чилдрена зайти чтоб там тоже перебирать.

Comment: по объяснению ничего не понятно: добавь в вопрос свой код с пояснением что именно в нем работает не так

Comment: сделайте функцию A(X) - которая принимает узел X, добавляет ему потомков, и для каждого вызывает функцию A(X.children[i]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уверен, что код далек от идеала оптимальности, но дольше раздумывать над ним в данный момент не досуг)

На выходе объект такого же вида, как и на входе, но с рекурсивно уложенными потомками. В корне массива, с приведенными данными, остаются только три объекта с номерами 1, 2 и 2.2.1.2.1.2 (сирота, увы).

```
var data = {"Data": [{"Uzel": "asd","Number": "1","Parent": "0","Update": "3"},{"Uzel": "asd","Number": "1.1","Parent": "1","Update": "2"},{"Uzel": "asd","Number": "2.2.1.2.1.2","Parent": "2.2.1.2.1","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "asd","Number": "1.1.1","Parent": "1.1","Update": "2"},{"Uzel": "asd","Number": "1.1.2","Parent": "1.1","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "zxc","Number": "1.1.3","Parent": "1.1","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "ert","Number": "1.1.4","Parent": "1.1","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "fgh","Number": "1.2","Parent": "1","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "cvb","Number": "1.2.1","Parent": "1.2","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "2012 год ","Number": "1.2.2","Parent": "1.2","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "uio","Number": "1.2.3","Parent": "1.2","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "2014 год ","Number": "1.2.4","Parent": "1.2","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "xxx","Number": "1.2.5","Parent": "1.2","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "xxx","Number": "1.3","Parent": "1","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "zzz","Number": "1.3.1","Parent": "1.3","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "aaa","Number": "1.3.2","Parent": "1.3","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "qqq","Number": "1.3.3","Parent": "1.3","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "vvv","Number": "1.3.4","Parent": "1.3","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "vvv","Number": "1.4","Parent": "1","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "www","Number": "1.4.1","Parent": "1.4","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "eee","Number": "1.4.2","Parent": "1.4","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "uuu","Number": "1.4.3","Parent": "1.4","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "iii","Number": "1.4.4","Parent": "1.4","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "ttt","Number": "1.4.5","Parent": "1.4","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "uuu","Number": "1.4.6","Parent": "1.4","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "nnn","Number": "1.5","Parent": "1","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "ooo","Number": "1.5.1","Parent": "1.5","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "nnn","Number": "1.5.2","Parent": "1.5","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "ppp","Number": "1.5.3","Parent": "1.5","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "bbb","Number": "1.5.4","Parent": "1.5","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "fff","Number": "1.5.5","Parent": "1.5","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "jjj","Number": "1.5.6","Parent": "1.5","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "lll","Number": "2","Parent": "0","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "mmm","Number": "2.1","Parent": "2","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "eee","Number": "2.1.1","Parent": "2.1","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "rrr","Number": "2.1.1.1","Parent": "2.1.1","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "opop","Number": "2.1.1.1.1","Parent": "2.1.1.1","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "asd","Number": "2.1.1.1.2","Parent": "2.1.1.1","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "asd","Number": "2.1.1.1.3","Parent": "2.1.1.1","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "asd","Number": "2.1.1.2","Parent": "2.1.1","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "asd","Number": "2.1.1.2.1","Parent": "2.1.1.2","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "fgh","Number": "2.1.1.2.2","Parent": "2.1.1.2","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "tyu","Number": "2.1.1.3","Parent": "2.1.1","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "uio","Number": "2.1.1.4","Parent": "2.1.1","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "zxc","Number": "2.1.1.5","Parent": "2.1.1","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "dsa","Number": "2.1.1.5.1","Parent": "2.1.1.5","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "poi","Number": "2.1.2","Parent": "2.1","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "qaxz","Number": "2.1.2.1","Parent": "2.1.2","Update": "0"},{"Uzel": "ert","Number": "2.1.2.1.1","Parent": "2.1.2.1","Update": "0"}]};
data = data.Data;

//первым проходом разложим элементы под ключи, определенные в Number
var indexedData = {};
for(var k in data){
    indexedData[data[k].Number] = data[k];
}

//здесь разложим item'ы по родителям. никакой рекурсии, все на первом уровне. 
for(var i in indexedData){
    var item = indexedData[i];
    if(indexedData[item.Parent]){
        if(!indexedData[item.Parent].children) indexedData[item.Parent].children = [];
        indexedData[item.Parent].children.push(item);
    }
}

data = {"Data": []};

//а здесь удалим из корня всех, для кого есть родитель, ведь в корне должны остаться только старшие элементы иерархии.
//т.к. удаляем одним проходом, то складываем удаленные ключи в массив и на следующих итерациях проверяем наличие и в нем.
//благодаря ссылочной работе JS, из первого уровня удалятся ссылки на item'ы, но они останутся в иерархии объектов на своих правильных местах. 
var deletedKeys = [];
for(var i in indexedData){
    if(indexedData[indexedData[i].Parent] || deletedKeys.indexOf(indexedData[i].Parent) !== -1){
        deletedKeys.push(i);
        delete indexedData[i];
    } else {
        data.Data.push(indexedData[i]);
    }
}

console.log('data: ', data);
```

Comment: а зачем делать: `data[k].Number.toString()`?

Comment: @Grundy гм. да, лишнее осталось от экспериментов, забыл вычистить.